# How to disable camera → Google Photos sync on Android 9?

Tags: google, privacy, google-photos

Similar to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25537/5934), but Google has somehow wormed their way around my settings:

- Photos → Settings → Backup & sync is *off.*
- Photos → Device folders → Camera → Back up (sic) & sync is *off.*
- Camera → Settings → Data storage is set to "Save picture to phone."

Even so, this morning I got a creepy reminder that Google Photos has my image, and that they have "helpfully" post-processed it. Short of breaking my phone in half (or rooting it), how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: One option I'm not sure you like probably is disabling that app. As you're short of rooting, installing LineageOS with F-Droid instead of GApps… OK OK, I won't go any further :) Works fine for me many years now, but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, I've disabled it and taken away its storage privileges :) Do you mind posting that as an answer? I did go down the alternative OS a couple times, but the pain was excruciating.

Comment: Sure – done with additional details for those who don't know where to do so. // No pain for me at all with LOS, and the battery lasts much longer without GApps. Not sure what hit you as excruciating; be welcome to talk in our chat room, I'll see that I can respond (even if asynchronously). Maybe that can be tackled, too.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option (and maybe hence easiest overlooked) is disabling the *Google Photos* app altogether (in *Settings › Apps* make sure you show "all apps", scroll to *Google Photos* and tap the "disable" button).

Revoking storage permissions from this app cannot hurt (who knows what might still invoke one of its intents; still in *Settings › Apps* tap the "wheel" icon in the upper-right corner, select "Permissions", then "Storage", scroll to the app, and toggle it off; you might have to do that before disabling the app as afterwards it might no longer show up here).